# Which events are suppressed by IsHitTestVisible

Tags: events, uwp, hittest, uielement

I cannot find the answer in MSDN documentation.

All I want is a list of UIElement's events which are suppressed when IsHitTestVisible = false.

It must be here somewhere but I can't find it. It is for a UWP project but I'm guessing it will be almost the same as WPF

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly the "IsHitTestVisible" property does not enable or disable any event it simply prevents the control from accepting any mouse input, you can still use your keyboard though...

Comment: It was badly phrased. I should have said suppressed. I just wanted to find a definitive list of which events will not take place. Maybe Hover, or the scroll wheel would still work for a listbox. I searched and searched and couldn't find a list. (Not even on StackOverflow)

Comment: @Paulustrious There is no list for the which events are suppressed by IsHitTestVisible. You should be able to test the event with `IsHitTestVisible`.